# Search a LONGTEXT field, and display results

Tags: php, mysql, search, text, statements

Okay, So short and sweet.
I have a field in my database that is LONGTEXT. This field usually has around 2,000 lines of text in each of these.

What I need it to do, is go through this LONGTEXT field and take out the line that has what is inputted to it.
(Sorry, I am horrible at explaining things)

For example, I originally used .txt files, but decided that MySQL was a much easier way to go as I do have a little bit of experience in it. I have this code.

```
function searchcode($search)
{
  $count = '0';
  $lines = file('file.txt');
  foreach($lines as $line)
  {
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    {
      echo "<tr><td>" . $line . "</td></tr>";
      $count++;
    }
  }
  echo "<tr><td style='border-top: 2px solid #000;'>$search was taken a total of $count times.</td></tr>";
}


CODE FOR SEARCHING FOR: searchcode("Camera");
```

This will look though the .txt file I want it to and display the lines based on what $search is. I want exactly this, but with MySQL.

In this example I was searching for a camera. And it would look through the .txt file and boom, every line with the word camera in it would display. (And the count of it obviously.)

**LETS MAKE THIS CRYSTAL CLEAR: I'm looking for something to search the longtext field. Then display results based on a certain word.**

I already know about the LIKE syntax, but I have no actual idea on how to use it!

**EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT**

[-Database-]

ID---------Date---------Information

1 ---------3-4-2012----camera has been removed. Jacket has been removed. camera has been added.

[-MySQL Page-]

MySQL Code Here

[-Webpage-]

Camera has been removed.

Camera has been added.

Answer (score 0):

use this Query.

```
SELECT ROUND((LENGTH(`column_name`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`column_name`, 'search_keyword', '')))/LENGTH('search_keyword')) FROM table
```

for example if the table have column "details"

```
id          details
1           this is one of the best product in the india
```

if we want to match and find count of  the text "the" in the "details" column, then use this query

```
SELECT ROUND((LENGTH(`details`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`details`, 'the', '')))/LENGTH('the')) as count FROM table
```

Output :

```
count = 3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this one a bit? All of that seems a bit...Weird to me.

Comment: So, that seems like it's only counting something, I'm not looking to count up stuff. I'm looking to Read each line of my LONGTEXT field, and then search for a specific word and each lines that contains that word would be outputted.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to make sure you have mysql-server, mysql-client, php-mysql and php-mysqli installed and configured on the server, I also suggest using [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) for a friendly mysql administration.

Create the actual table:

```
CREATE TABLE code (
   id int(11) not null auto_increment,
   file longtext,
   primary key(id)
)
```

The next step is to choose mysql access method, you can choose [mysqli or pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

The following example will show you how to do it with mysqli:

```
class db{
    function query($query, $show_error=true)
    {
        $time_before = $this->get_real_time();

        if(!$this->db_id) $this->connect(DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME, DBHOST);

        if(!($this->query_id = mysqli_query($this->db_id, $query) )) {

            $this->mysql_error = mysqli_error($this->db_id);
            $this->mysql_error_num = mysqli_errno($this->db_id);

            if($show_error) {
                $this->display_error($this->mysql_error, $this->mysql_error_num, $query);
            }
        }

        $this->MySQL_time_taken += $this->get_real_time() - $time_before;

        $this->query_num ++;

        return $this->query_id;
    }

function get_array($query_id = '')
{
    if ($query_id == '') $query_id = $this->query_id;

    return mysqli_fetch_array($query_id);
}

    function display_error($error, $error_num, $query = '')
    {
        if($query) {
            // Safify query
            $query = preg_replace("/([0-9a-f]){32}/", "********************************", $query); // Hides all hashes
            $query_str = "$query";
        }

        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <title>MySQL Fatal Error</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-style: normal;
            color: #000000;
        }
        -->
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <font size="4">MySQL Error!</font> 
            <br />------------------------<br />
            <br />

            <u>The Error returned was:</u> 
            <br />
                <strong>'.$error.'</strong>

            <br /><br />
            </strong><u>Error Number:</u> 
            <br />
                <strong>'.$error_num.'</strong>
            <br />
                <br />

            <textarea name="" rows="10" cols="52" wrap="virtual">'.$query_str.'</textarea><br />

        </body>
        </html>';

        exit();
    }
}

define ("DBHOST", "localhost");
define ("DBNAME", "DBNAME");
define ("DBUSER", "DBUSER");
define ("DBPASS", "PASS");
define ("PREFIX", "PREFIX");
define ("USERPREFIX", "USERPREFIX");
define ("COLLATE", "utf8");

$db = new db;
```

Now you are ready to access mysql

Insert some data:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO code (code) VALUES('{$text}')");
```

Select from code:

```
  $row=$db->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE file LIKE '%{$search}%'");
  while($row=$db->get_array()){
     /* your original code */
     foreach($row['text'] as $line){
       if(strpos($line, $search) !== false){
         echo "<tr><td>" . $line . "</td></tr>";
         $count++;
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I suppose I should mention, I have never used mysqli before, so I don't understand any of that... Well, I understand a bit of it, however, some just doesnt make sense to me.